# Protect an ASPX page with a password

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making a page that the user should enter his password again to open and when he navigate away and come back again he should re-enter the password. NO SESSIONS OR COOKIES, just a simple page you enter the password you view it.

How can I do this ?

Comment: so,where is your problem in code?

Comment: I'm new to ASP and don't know how to make such thing

Comment: @Fady you keep asking for asp classic ... what's is your file extension? `.asp` or `.aspx` as your previous questions were ASP.NET

Comment: @Fady did you ever take some time as see the **free ASP.NET courses** in ASP.NET website? they have for **all versions of ASP.NET**: [**WebForms**](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) *(what you are using)*, [**MVC**](http://www.asp.net/mvc) and [**Web Pages**](http://www.asp.net/web-pages) check all courses screencasts in the right sidebar... You will learn to do much more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two divs.

One which contains the main content and other containing a textbox and button.

```
<div id="MainDiv" runat="server" Visible="false">Main Content goes here. </div>
```

And the login div

```
<div id="LoginDiv" runat="server" Visible="true">
        <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="LoginButton_Click" /></div>
```

On login button click handler, check the password and toggle the visibility.

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(PasswordTextBox.Text=="Password")
            {
                MainDiv.Visible=true;
                LoginDiv.Visible=false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: BTW `Equals` is a little bit slower that if you use `==` when comparing 2 strings... learn that when handling LINQ :/

Comment: Ok. Once ran into some problem using == in LINQ so stopeed using it. Don't remember the scenario were it failed. It was meant to be a easy solution, perhaps he the OP is learning to make things and it would not go in production...:)...

Answer (score 3):

you should use **2 pages**, one to enter the password, and the other to show the page...

the password page, will have a `form` as `POST` that points to `page2.aspx`

example of `protected.aspx`:

```
<form action="page2.aspx" mehod="post">
  Pasword: <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
</form>
```

and the `Page_Load` event on `page2.aspx` should be something like

```
if(Request["pwd"] == null || Request["pwd"] != "123") {
  Response.Redirect("InvalidPassword.aspx");
}
```

Comment: so I should redirect them also when Request["pwd"] is not set .. how ?

Comment: `Page_Load` is the event that fires before it render the page, here you can set up everything as nothing was sent to the browser. The condition: `if(Request["pwd"] == null || Request["pwd"] != "123")` will insure that the `pwd` field was sent and it's the password you are expecting, in this case `123`. If it is not, then it will redirect to a page called `InvalidPassword.aspx`, otherwise, it will continue and load the page.